# Get text of label with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, label, onclientclick

I want to do very simple thing, but I'm not success. I have button and label on my asp.net page and I want to get text of label after clicking on button. Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicWebApplication.WebForm2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function f() 
        {
            var g = $('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').val();  // Also I tried .text() and .html()
            alert(g);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <p></p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="f();"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you give example how to use it?

Comment: I don't see the jQuery script loaded anywhere in your code. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try this:

```
var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').val();
```

or this:

```
var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html();
```

you are missing the #

add this in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to add the jquery script included look at my edited answer

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the html() function.

`$('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html();`

You're also missing the # to make it an ID you're searching for. Without the #, it's looking for a tag type.

Comment: var g = $('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').val();  // Also I tried .text() and .html()

Answer (score 2):

No solution here worked for me. Instead I added a class to the label and was able to select it that way.

`<asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="myLabel1Class" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>`

`$(".myLabel1Class").val()`

And, as mentioned by others, make sure you have your jquery loaded.

Comment: I got this to work using $(".myLabel1Class").html()

Thank you Dr Jones!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<%=this.Label1.Text%>
```

Answer (score 0):

try document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text or innerHTML OTHERWISE LOAD JQUERY SCRIPT AND put your code as it is....

Answer (score 0):

for the line you wrote

> var g = $('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').val();  // Also I tried .text() and .html()

you missed adding #. it should be like this

> var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text();

also I do not prefer using this method

that's because if you are calling a control in master or nested master page or if you are calling a control in page from master. Also controls in Repeater. regardless the MVC. this will cause problems.

you should ALWAYS call the ID of the control directly. like this

> $('#ControlID')

this is simple and clear.
but do not forget to set

> ClientIDMode="Static"

in your controls to remain with same ID name after render. that's because ASP.net will modify the ID name in HTML rendered file in some contexts 
i.e. the page is for Master page the control name will be ConetentPlaceholderName_controlID

I hope it clears the question
Good Luck

Answer (score -2):

It's simple, set a specific value for that label (XXXXXXX for example) and run it, open html source of output (in browser) and look for XXXXXXX, you will see something like this `<span id="mylabel">XXXXXX</span>` it's what you want, the ID of `<span>` (I think it's usually same as Label name in asp code) now you can get its value by innerHTML or another method in JQuery

Comment: $('.mylabel').html(); for JQuery

Comment: That would select a class named mylabel, not an ID.

Comment: maybe this $('mylabel').html(); I'm not familiar with JQ

Comment: `$('#mylabel').html()`, like the other posts.