# jQuery value from a Label (VB.net) works with Textbox

Tags: jquery, vb.net

Issue:

jquery not picking up text/value from a ASP Label but does from a Textbox.

I have read up articles such as [Get text of label with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972666/get-text-of-label-with-jquery) and tried .val .value and .text

So if I put Label1 then nothing happens. If I put Label2 it works?!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $('#PropertyMap').showmap(document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID%>').val);
                            });
                        </script>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="harrogate"></asp:Label>
                           <asp:Textbox ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="harrogate"></asp:Textbox>
```

Comment: So you want to get text of label?

Comment: If you will do something like alert($('#Label1').attr('Text')); i think it will work for you

Comment: Other way, I want the Label to be ASP:Label to be picked up.

Comment: You can use ClientIDMode="Static" on your label and then you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ASP:Label` will be rendered as a `span`. To get the text of a span in JavaScript, you should change it to something like this:

```
$('#PropertyMap').showmap(document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML);
```

Or, since you're using jQuery anyway:

```
$('#PropertyMap').showmap($('#' + <%= Label1.ClientID%>).text());
```

Comment: I used the top one with .innerHTML The .text version did not work